# how to make union range faster for large loops

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

I have a sub that becomes very slow after about 5000 iterations in a loop.
It's quick otherwise.

Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

Excel 2013 (15.0.4701.1001) MSO (15.0.4701.1000) 64-bit

```
Sub UnionSlow()

Dim ColArray() As Variant
Dim NumLastRow, NumRow, Cnt As Long
Dim CurCell As String
Dim rngPRC As Range

'Set an arbitrary row so range is not empty

Set rngPRC = Rows(1)

'Get the total number of rows in the sheet 

TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Load the first column into an array (v quick)

ColArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(TotalRows, 1)).Value

'Now loop through the array and add ROWS to the RANGE depending on a condition

For NumRow = 1 To TotalRows

       CurCell = ColArray(NumRow, 1)

       If CurCell = "PRC" Then Set rngPRC = Union(rngPRC, Rows(NumRow))

Next NumRow

'Display a few things

MsgBox "Areas count " & rngPRC.Areas.Count
MsgBox "Address " & rngPRC.Address
MsgBox "Length array " & UBound(ColArray) & " items"

rngPRC.EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 128)

End Sub
```

So the thing is that this loads the array very quickly and changes the color very quickly.
What slows it down is building the range of rows.
Up to 2000 rows it's quick (less than 1 second)
Up to 5000 rows it's slower (about 5 seconds)
At about 20000 rows it takes about 10 minutes

I'm very new to VBA so please tell me if I'm being daft here.

thanks for looking
Antony

Comment: Yes UNION is slow for large numbers of areas. You need to find an alternate method: I have used a method of creating an array of start and end row pairs where the end row increments if its adjacent.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is another statement that slows down in this way. Whenever you make `rngPRC` bigger, the interpreter has to find a larger block of memory, copy the enlarged `rngPRC` to it and release the old `rngPRC` for garbage collection. Inevitable, this will get sloower and slooower.  Charles is correct you must rethink you approach. I have used the technique he describes successful.  However, in this case, I believe AutoFilter for column 1 = "PRC" would be neater and faster approach.

Comment: @TonyDallimore excellent suggestion re AutoFilter.

Comment: If the intent of this code is the final step (colouring) - then you can skip code altogether and use conditional formatting

Comment: Thank you all for your help here. I'm amazed at the reaction. Good explanation from @TonyDallimore which really helps me understand what's going wrong. I'm going to try the autofilter approach and see where that gets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with one of the comments stating that autofilter would work well in this situation. Here is a draft solution:

```
AutoFilterMode = False
TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngPRC = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(TotalRows, 1))

rngPRC.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="PRC"

If rngPRC.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then 'check if rows exist

  Set rngPRC = rngPRC.Resize(rngPRC.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0) _
         .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

  'perform your operations here:  
  rngPRC.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 128)
End If

AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your range one row at a time:

- If your range is contiguous from top to bottom:

  1. loop from the top to bottom
  2. create one range
  3. set the color
- If your range is non-contiguous:

  1. start at the top
  2. loop through to find the break point
  3. union that to your range
  4. loop to find find the next range start point
  5. return to step 2
  6. lather, rinse, repeat until there are no more 'start points'
  7. set the color of your built range

This will at least minimize the number of unions you have to do.

Comment: thank you freeman. I should have mentioned that every single row will have some action performed on it so looping is probably the easiest. ps up the reds !

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use loop at all - use FIND instead.

If you copy the **FindAll** code from Chip Pearsons site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

You can then use this short procedure to do what you're after (copied from Chips site with a couple of changes to make it work for you:

```
Sub TestFindAll()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindWhat As Variant
    Dim FoundCells As Range

    Set SearchRange = Sheet1.Columns(1)
    FindWhat = "PRC"
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Not Found", vbOKOnly
    Else
        FoundCells.EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 128)
    End If

End Sub
```

It should be fairly easy to update the FindAll function to work faster by removing code not relevant to your needs.

Comment: `Find` is useful for a few needles in a haystack, at the other extreme it involves glueing together an entire range of "sucessful finds", cell by cell - which is the current code from the OP. So it depends how scare the *PRC* values are.

Comment: thank you. i'll use this findall on another project. I should have said that each line in my csv file needs some action performing on it, mostly changing the style, so i'll either loop through or try the autofilter suggestion.

Comment: Glad it's of some use.  @brettdj is correct with his needles in a haystack analogy but I'd say even with the lower value of 2000 rows it's worth using Find as there could easily be 100 rows between occurrences.  If you will be performing an action on pretty much every row then I'd go with the autofilter method.